# Laravel 5.5 orderby count and paginate

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get to order the results by count in laravel 5.5 but haven't found any simple yet working method so far.

What I have tried for example:

```
$videos = Video::withCount('com_num')->where('active', '1')->orderByDesc('com_num_count')->paginate(51);
```

But this just gives me:

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::com_num()

Is this possible somehow while using the Laravel's pagination?

Comment: Have you defined the `com_num` relationship on your `Video` model?

Comment: Also, say that your relationship name is `com_num`, you'd have to `->orderBy('com_num_count')` then (add _count to the end).

Comment: @AaronFahey, I have actually not done that. I thought I can just use it directly without relationship.

Comment: @devk, sorry. That was a typo in the example. Will fix, yes I have it com_num_count.

Comment: @EmJeiEn this should help https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models